# TCL - feeding STDIN to exec

Tags: tcl, exec, stdin

I'm trying to implement a retry mechanism when executing an external program using TCL. I'm having some issues when trying to feed STDIN to the external program. I'm now working with a simplified example trying to solve the issue. Take the following python script (simple.py):

```
x = raw_input()
y = raw_input()
print x + y
```

Inputs 2 strings from the output will be the concatenation result of the strings.

Now the following command works from the TCL interpreter:

```
% exec python stuff.py << 1\n2
12
```

However when I try to split it in separate commands, or add them to a string before doing this, it fails.

Fail 1:

```
% set cmd "python simple.py << 1\n2"
% exec $cmd
couldn't execute "python simple.py << 1
2": no such file or directory
```

Fail 2:

```
% set cmd1 "python simple.py"
% set cmd2 "1\n2"
% exec $cmd1 << $cmd2
```

couldn't execute "python simple.py": no such file or directory

Fail 3:

```
% set fullCommandString "exec python simple.py << 1\n2"
% eval $fullCommandString
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 2, in <module>
    y = raw_input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

The 3rd case seems that starts the script, but it interprets both lines of STDIN as one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl's commands do not reinterpret whitespace in their arguments by default. `exec` is one of these, and it follows the same rules. That means that you need to tell Tcl to interpret that list of words *as a list of words* as otherwise it is just a string. Fortunately, there's `{*}` for this; the expansion <s>operator</s> syntax interprets the rest of the word as a Tcl list, and uses the words out of that list at the point where you write it. It's very useful I find.

The simplest to fix is actually your second case:

```
% set cmd1 "python simple.py"
% set cmd2 "1\n2"
% exec {*}$cmd1 << $cmd2
```

You can fix the first and third by adding Tcl list quoting to ensure the `1\n2` is still interpreted as a single word (as otherwise newline is a perfectly reasonable list item separator).

```
% set cmd "python simple.py << {1\n2}"
% exec $cmd
```

```
% set fullCommandString "exec python simple.py << {1\n2}"
% eval $fullCommandString
```

The third can be written more economically though:

```
% set fullCommandString "exec python simple.py << {1\n2}"
% {*}$fullCommandString
```

As a rule of thumb, if you see `eval` in modern Tcl (note: *not* `namespace eval` or `interp eval` or `uplevel`) then it's usually an indication that some code could be made more efficient and to have fewer bugs by switching to using expansion carefully.

---

**tl;dr:** Put `{*}` before `$cmd1` in your second example to get the idiomatic fix.